# How to get the process name by pid in Linux using Python?

Tags: python, linux

I want to get the process name, given it's pid in python.
Is there any direct method in python?

Comment: What do you mean "per line"?

Comment: It means that print pid and its name per line.
not important

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to see the running process, you can just use `os` module to execute the `ps` unix command

```
import os
os.system("ps")
```

This will list the processes.

But if you want to get process name by ID, you can try `ps -o cmd= <pid>`
So the python code will be

```
import os
def get_pname(id):
    return os.system("ps -o cmd= {}".format(id))
print(get_pname(1))
```

The better method is using `subprocess` and pipes.

```
import subprocess
def get_pname(id):
    p = subprocess.Popen(["ps -o cmd= {}".format(id)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    return str(p.communicate()[0])
name = get_pname(1)
print(name)
```

Comment: @Mahsa just use that function in a loop ie for a list of pid, just loop through that list and use the function

Comment: when you `return os.system("whatever")` you are probably getting the exitcode (0) rather than the string that the command outputs

Answer (score 46):

The [`psutil`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil) package makes this very easy.

```
import psutil

process = psutil.Process(pid)

process_name = process.name()
```

Comment: This is the better module. I was trying to remember what this was called.  It wasn't procfs.

Comment: I get an error:
'TypeError: 'str' object is not callable'

Comment: @Mahsa, you're using an old version of `psutil`. You should generally upgrade, but for now just use `process.name` as a string instead of calling it.

Answer (score 0):

Command name (only the executable name):

```py
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen

def get_cmd(pid):
    with Popen(f"ps -q {pid} -o comm=", shell=True, stdout=PIPE) as p:
        return p.communicate()[0]
```

Command with all its arguments as a string:

```py
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen

def get_args(pid):
    with Popen(f"ps -q {pid} -o cmd=", shell=True, stdout=PIPE) as p:
        return p.communicate()[0]
```