# Name process when creating it with python's subprocess.Popen()

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I am using python's subprocess.Popen() to run multiple subprocesses at a time. Each time a process is terminated, I want to print something like this to the shell:
`process ABC has been terminated` 
ABC being a name that I give to the process myself.
I thought maybe there is a way to achieve this using some code like this: `process.name()`

Is there a way to do that through subprocess.Popen()?

Comment: You can use `dict` with popen object as a key and name as a value;

Comment: You can get the pid of the process from Popen and then use the approach int the following link to get the process name. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32295395/how-to-get-the-process-name-by-pid-in-linux-using-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a textbook example of what you use inheritance for.

```py
import subprocess

class NamedPopen(subprocess.Popen):
     """
     Like subprocess.Popen, but returns an object with a .name member
     """
     def __init__(self, *args, name=None, **kwargs):
         self.name = name
         super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

fred = NamedPopen('sleep 11; echo "yabba dabba doo"', shell=True, name="fred")
barney = NamedPopen('sleep 22; echo "hee hee, okay fred"', name="barney", shell=True)
print('... stay tuned ...')
fred.wait()
barney.wait()
```

Just take care to not pick an attribute name which the parent class uses for something else.

Comment: This makes sense, Thanks. When running a copy-paste of your code though I'm getting this error: ```TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'name'``` Am I missing a self somewhere or what?

Comment: It works for me on Python 3.7.2; can you try renaming the `name` attribute and printing out all of `kwargs` before calling `super().__init()`?

Comment: I made sure the ```name``` attribute is not used by the parent class. I tried to rename it anyway but it gave me the same error. I also tried printing args, but it seems as if it's not reaching that line, I think it's getting stuck at ```def __init__```

Comment: Well, it works for me, and now, it works for https://repl.it/repls/StrictShinyWireframe (with shorter sleeps).

Answer (score 0):

There is no portable way to do so using `subprocess`, you could use another package in combination with it, you can check the https://github.com/dvarrazzo/py-setproctitle library.

Using that module you can name a process title, and then access to it and print the desired output easily.